# Android - Float Button Screenshot

Tags: android, button, service, screenshot

I need to create an application that opens another app, and allowed me to take a screenshot of the second app, and then go back to my application and make a report.

I did it with FileObserver, but I had a problem with Android 6.0 (Marshmallow), so I planned to create a "float button" that was present the hole time in the second app, which allows me take the screenshot and go back to my app.

The problem appears while taking the screenshot, since it needs a View and I do not know how to do it.

Any of you has already done it? Or do knows how to?

Thanks

Comment: I need to do the same thing any luck on how to go about this?